# Rails Undo link in view for changes in Audited

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, undo-redo

when I added the following code to the lib

https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited/pull/381/files

I do not know how to call in view. Can you advise me how to call this method?

I was thinking about http://github.com/airblade/paper_trail, but I do not want to have many gems.

Comment: why do you want to call undo method in view? why not in controller?

Comment: because when I update I want a link to undo in view. The logic is in lib/audited/audit.rb. Maybe next logic can I add on controller. Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 2):

1.create a url/route for undo link action

routes.rb

```
get 'undo', to: 'audit#undo'
```

2.create its controller/action

audit_controller.rb

```
def undo
  current_user.audits.last.undo
end
```

3.add the undo link in view

your_view.html.erb

```
<a href="/undo"></a>
```

Comment: post method is better than get, but if you want a <a> link, using get method.